# Angular Components Passing value issue from html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, angular-controller

So iv been working on some angular code lately and i'm fairly new. I really tried a lot to solve this issue but Im literally blocked. So, my issue is that I created a angular component shown below.

```
angular.module('fab', ['ngMaterial']);
 angular.module('fab').
 component('menuBar', {
 bindings: {
        id :"="
    },
 controller: function MenuBarController() {

  this.$onInit = function(){
    this.section = this.id;

  } 


 },
      templateUrl:'/frontend/templates/bootstrap_menu_bar.html',
}
);
```

and im trying to bind a value to 'id' here from the html source shown below.

```
<html>
<body ng-app='fab'> 
<menu-bar id="section1"></menu-bar>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the template that is referred in the component. I try to access it using

```
<li ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.section"><a href="#section1">{{x}}</a></li>
```

Could someone help and explain why the value id wont bind to the component here?. Iv been at it for so long and this would help me progress in my efforts of grasping angular.

**strong text**

Comment: you are missing a few things here. first of all, you are only binding an app but not a controller. second, you are using ng-repeat for a single var. it only works on arrays.

Comment: <li ><a href="#section1">{{$ctrl.section}}</a></li>. I tried this too but no luck. Also to your first advice, does a controller have to be specified in the component tag?